# Create a link with scraped image name

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I scrape a website and also images from this same website.
I use a custom Pipeline for the image.
I'd like to create a link in my lists from an URL (for example "www.urls.com/image") and add the name of the corresponding image.

My spider.py:

```
import json
import scrapy
import re
import pkgutil

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from auctions_results.items import AuctionItem
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

from datetime import datetime

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_file = pkgutil.get_data(
            "auctions_results", "json/input/scrape_demo_db.json")
        self.data = json.loads(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['gm_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
            data = AuctionItem()

            data["marque"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").extract_first().strip().split(" ", 2)[1]

            data["auction_house"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().split("-", 1)[0].strip()
            data["auction_country"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().rsplit(",", 1)[1].strip()
            data["auction_date"] = caritem.css("div.date::text").extract_first().replace(",", "").strip()

            data["image_urls"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a img::attr(src)").extract_first()
            data["image_path"] = "urls.com/" + NAME OF THE SCRAPED IMAGE

            item['results'].append(data)

        yield item
```

My image pipeline:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class DownloadImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for result in item['results']:
            image_url = result['image_urls']
            if image_url is not None:
                request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url)
                yield request
```

A sample of the output:

```
[{
"gm_url": "url",
"results": [{
    "marque": "ferrari",
    "auction_house": "auction",
    "auction_country": "japan",
    "auction_date": "2019",
    "image_urls": "imgurl"
},
{
    "marque": "porsche",
    "auction_house": "auction2",
    "auction_country": "gb",
    "auction_date": "2018",
    "image_urls": "imgurl2"
}],
"images": [
{
    "url": "imgurl",
    "path": "full/0c2d1678d25dfed305d9a1f64366f005f2c3a138.jpg",
    "checksum": "e33f726186f72e2e9810555615964fb1"
},
{
    "url": "imgurl2",
    "path": "full/758825eeb421e6ef49e73bd6af2e0eeb9090cfe1.jpg",
    "checksum": "c172e40ab961108bdd5be1874d688f62"
}]
```

Now I'd like to add a key-value "image_path" in my example" in each result with my URL and add the name of the image to create another URL.
Is it possible to do this in Python?

Comment: as I remeber Pipeline has method which generate name for downloaded file and it can get informaction from `item` (or maby `request['meta']`) - so you could create name in `parse()`, put in `item`, use it to create your url in item, and later use the same name from item in Pipeline.

Comment: see [file_path](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/images.py#L167) in pipeline's source code. You can create own `file_path` in your `DownloadImagesPipeline`

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it now but you can create own name in `parse()` and later use it in `Pipeline`

In `Spider`:

- create `filename` and `url` in `parse()`:

  ```
      data["filename"] = '... create your filename ...'

      data["image_path"] = "urls.com/" + data["filename"]

      item['results'].append(data)
  ```

In `DownloadImagesPipeline`:

- in `get_media_requests` use this `filename` in `meta=` in `Request()`

  ```
      if image_url is not None:

          filename = result['filename']

          request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url, meta={'filename:', filename} )

          yield request
  ```
- create `file_path` which generates name for downloaded file and use `filename`  downloaded file

  ```
  def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
      return request.meta['filename']
  ```

---

More or less all code

```
def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
            data = AuctionItem()

            data["marque"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").extract_first().strip().split(" ", 2)[1]

            data["auction_house"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().split("-", 1)[0].strip()
            data["auction_country"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().rsplit(",", 1)[1].strip()
            data["auction_date"] = caritem.css("div.date::text").extract_first().replace(",", "").strip()

            data["image_urls"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a img::attr(src)").extract_first()

            data["filename"] = '... your filename ...'

            data["image_path"] = "urls.com/" + data["filename"]

            item['results'].append(data)


class DownloadImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for result in item['results']:
            image_url = result['image_urls']
            if image_url is not None:

                filename = result['filename']

                request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url, meta={'filename:', filename} )
                yield request

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return request.meta['filename']
```

Comment: I have a `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required`. Besides, the list with the results is not created.

Comment: error should show which line makes problem. I can't run it now. I would have to create project or standalone application to test it.

Comment: I understand, the error appears with this line: `request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url, meta={
                                         'filename:', filename})`

Comment: now I see mistake in  dictionary. it has to be  `{'filename': filename}` instead of `{'filename:', filename}`. Accidently I created `set()` instead of `dict()`. Probably I had `print('filename:', filename)` and I copied it.

Comment: now you have to create unique filename for every image.